# UISlider in UITableViewCell Moving to Other UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uislider

I have a `UISlider` in a `UITableViewCell`. I added some code so it could expand when or retract in "Landscape" and "Portrait" mode. However now it jumps into other `UITableviewcells`. Anybody have any ideas why? Here is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)didRotate {
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Configure the cell...

static NSString *CellIdentifier;

if ((indexPath.section==kSectionSlider) && (indexPath.row==kSettingSlider)){
    CellIdentifier=@"SliderCell";
}
else{
    CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ([CellIdentifier isEqual:@"Cell"]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else if ([CellIdentifier isEqual:@"SliderCell"]){
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.65*tableView.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height);
        UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        slider.continuous = YES;
        slider.value = _value;
        _slider=slider;
        cell.accessoryView = slider;
    }
}

CGRect frame;
frame = tableView.frame;
frame.size.width=0.65*frame.size.width;
_slider.frame=frame;

switch(indexPath.section){
    case kSectionSlider:{
                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f“,_value];
        }
    }break;    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: If two cells are overlapping, it generally indicates that the height of cells are not set correctly. Can you show the code in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: what do you mean by "jumps"?

Comment: Thanks. I am not implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath . What I mean by jumps is that the slider would either disappear or be on another UITableViewCell maybe 5 or 6 rows underneath. I think it has to do with the frame when I change it for the slider. I need this since the slider should update its size between landscape or portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to this line:

```
CGRect frame;
frame = tableView.frame;
frame.size.width=0.65*frame.size.width;
_slider.frame=frame;
```

I removed that and added this line when creating the UISlider:

```
slider.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Now everything works as expected. Thanks for assistance.